# Simple camera capture in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv, camera

I just want to preview then capture a snapshot from a device camera (webcam) in a WinForms C# application.

I've used this: [WebEye WebCameraControl](https://github.com/jacobbo/WebEye/tree/master/WebCameraControl), but it seems to fail on some machines/cameras. The description implies there's loads more out there, but I can't find any on NuGet that are for WinForms.

Any recommendations? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, like a built-in windows control that will just do it!

---

Edit:
In trying to add OpenCVSharp this is what I get:
[image]

Answer (score 13):

Try [OpenCVSharp](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp). A bit of a code snippet with a PictureBox and a Button:

```
VideoCapture capture;
Mat frame;
Bitmap image;
private Thread camera;
bool isCameraRunning = 0;

private void CaptureCamera() {
    camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
    camera.Start();
}

private void CaptureCameraCallback() {

    frame = new Mat();
    capture = new VideoCapture(0);
    capture.Open(0);

    if (capture.IsOpened()) {
        while (isCameraRunning) {

            capture.Read(frame);
            image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null) {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
        }
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (button1.Text.Equals("Start")) {
        CaptureCamera();
        button1.Text = "Stop";
        isCameraRunning = true;
    }
    else {
        capture.Release();
        button1.Text = "Start";
        isCameraRunning = false;
    }
}
```

**Full Code**

```cs
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Create class-level accesible variables
        VideoCapture capture;
        Mat frame;
        Bitmap image;
        private Thread camera;
        bool isCameraRunning = false;

        // Declare required methods
        private void CaptureCamera()
        {
            camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
            camera.Start();
        }

        private void CaptureCameraCallback()
        {
            frame = new Mat();
            capture = new VideoCapture(0);
            capture.Open(0);

            if (capture.IsOpened())
            {
                while (isCameraRunning)
                {
                    capture.Read(frame);
                    image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    }

                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                }
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CaptureCamera();
            button1.Text = "Stop";
            isCameraRunning = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (button1.Text.Equals("Start"))
            {
                CaptureCamera();
                button1.Text = "Stop";
                isCameraRunning = true;
            }
            else
            {
                capture.Release();
                button1.Text = "Start";
                isCameraRunning = false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosed(e);
            try
            {
                capture.Release();
                camera.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCameraRunning)
            {
                Bitmap snapshot = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);


                snapshot.Save(string.Format(@"D:\image.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                capture.Release();
                camera.Abort();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot take picture if the camera isn't capturing image!");
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

[image]

Here SaveButton save image to D:\location
if you feel any error try run as admin

you can find solution here:-
[working example](https://github.com/lavahasif/camera)

Comment: Thank you - looks good, but I can't find the definition of VideoCapture ... any idea?

Comment: Please get OpenCVSharp from Nuget. It's there.

Comment: That's what I've done, but VideoCapture is not defined hence my confusion. I've got `Mat` by using OpenCvSharp.CPlusPlus, but just using OpenCvSharp isn't giving me the VideoCapture definition. Oddness. Might try a restart...

Comment: From metadata: namespace OpenCvSharp {
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Video capturing class
    public class VideoCapture : DisposableCvObject {

Comment: Well, yes ... i've seen that in github. But the nuget build I've installed apparently doesn't have it. Maybe I've installed the wrong one or something? Can't be. See the screenshot added to the question. Confused!!

Comment: OpenCvSharp3-AnyCPU.3.4.1.20180319

Comment: Well, now I just get a black or with the occasional coloured dots for the first few lines of the image. Just leaving the comment for the next wanderer really. For some reason camera capture is never straight forward ... Thanks anyway!!

Comment: Why not just use the built in Ctrl + PrtSC combo. Then save it with saveFileDialog. If your not doing anything else.

Comment: Camera Capture @Halonic. Not screen capture. Also this is looking for software solutions.

Comment: Ok well for me when I created my own desktop screen recorder and camera capture, I used Aforge .dll it has screen capture. I can post an example. It's pretty straightforward. The same as you have drawing a bitmap.

Comment: I am facing a black screen instead of video. It does not work.